# Выбрать рандомно несколько элементов , и присвоить им класс

Tags: jquery

```
<div id=“blocks”>
    <div class=“block”></div>
    <div class=“block”></div>
    <div class=“block”></div>
    <div class=“block”></div>
    <div class=“block”></div>
    <div class=“block”></div>
    <div class=“block”></div>
</div>
```

Как рандомно выбрать 3 элемента и присовить им класс active

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var $el = $('blocks>div'),
   limit = 3,
   $elLength = $el.length,
   randEl;

for(var i=0; i<limit;){
  randEl = $el.eq(randomInteger(0, $elLength));
  if(!randEl.hasClass('active')){
     randEl.addClass('active');
     i++;
  }

}


function randomInteger(min, max) {
    var rand = min - 0.5 + Math.random() * (max - min + 1)
    rand = Math.round(rand);
    return rand;
  }
```

Comment: Зачем нужна функция `randomInteger()`, если ее нигде не вызывают?

Comment: @Sasha Omelchenko, опечатка. Исправил